# How to run a program automatically on printing

Tags: printing, java, configuration-management

I developed a simple application that show on screen my printers ink levels.

I'd like to run this program automatically every time that Ubuntu send to the printer the print command. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by adding a listener to your application and have it running in the backround.

If you look at the javax.print.PrintService; link to the documention found: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/PrintService.html) 
you will find a method called addPrintServiceAttributeListener which allows you to register a listener for print events.